# Replicating a figure of an article in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to replicate a figure from this [article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6517979). More specifically, I want to replicate Figure number 4, which I believe is the representation of Equation 9.

So far I have come up with this code:

```
% implementing equation 9 and figure 4
step   = 0.01;    t = 1:step:3600;
d      = 3;     % dimension
N      = 8000;  % number of molecules
H      = 0.01;  % H = [0.01,0.1,1] is in mol/micrometer^3  
H      = H*6.02214078^5; % hence I scaled the Avogadro's number (right or wrong?)
D      = 10;    % diffusion coefficient in micrometer^2/sec

u(1)   =  1./(1.^(d/2)); % inner function in equation 9; first pulse

for i = 2:numel(t)/1000
    u(i)     =  u(i-1)+(1./(i.^(d/2))); %  u-> the pulse number
    lmda(i)  = (1/(4*pi*D))*((N/(H)).*sum(u)).^(2/d);
end

figure;plot(lmda)
```

But I am not able to replicate it.

Equation 9

[image]
For details on the parameters, refer to the above code. The authors did mention that the summation in equation 9 is a Reimann Zeta series. Wonder if that has anything to do with the result?

Figure 4, which I am trying to replicate:

[image]

Could someone kindly tell me the mistake I am making?

P.s: This is not a homework.

Comment: @Wolfie I assumed that the pulses `u` are generated after a fixed period of time and not every 0.01 seconds

Comment: The problem is when you are scaling with the Avogadro number. The relevant line should read `H = H * 6.02214078e5`. This should solve your problem

Comment: @ammportal Thank you for pointing that mistake but still, I do not get the result

Comment: Well the Avogadro number is `6.022e23`, not `6.022e5`

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, it is `6.022e23`. But since I want to convert `H molecules/micrometer^3`  to molecules which means I have to scale the Avogadro's number by `e-18`. Therefore it becomes `6.022e5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem 1: You *think* you are scaling by Avogadro's number on this line

```
H = H*6.02214078^5;
```

In fact, you're scaling by approximately `7920=6.022^5`. If you wanted to scale by the Avogadro number then you should do:

```
H = H * 6.02214078e23 % = 6.02214078 * 10^23 : the Avogadro number
```

Problem 2: You aren't plotting against `t`, you're plotting against the sample number which doesn't really make sense (unless your `t` happened to be in integer seconds). Remove the `/1000` from your loop

```
for i = 2:numel(t)
    % ...
end
% Then plot
plot(t, lmda)
```

---

**At this stage we can see something is really wrong**. Now that we're scaling by the correct Avo number, the orders of magnitude are way out. I suggest that you trust the `H` in figure 4 and the `H` in equation 9 are the same `H`, it would be very confusing if the author intended anything different!

On that basis, I would suggest you are using the wrong `D`, `N`, or time between pulses. I've set up the pulse timing a bit clearer in my code below. I've also streamlined your loop somewhat using vectorisation, and removed the `H` scaling.

If you tweak it so `dtPulses=100` as well as `D=100`, then the plots are almost identical. You perhaps need to consider how these two numbers affect the result...

```
% implementing equation 9 and figure 4
d = 3;     % dimension
N = 8000;  % number of molecules
D = 100;   % diffusion coefficient in micrometer^2/sec

dtPulses = 10; % Seconds between pulses
tPulses = 1:dtPulses:3600; % Time array to plot against
nt = numel(tPulses);
i = 1:nt;  % pulse numbers
u = 1 ./ (i.^(d/2)); % inner function in equation 9: individual pulse
for k = 2:nt % Running sum
    u(k) = u(k-1)+u(k);
end
% Now plot for different H (mol/micrometer^3)
H = [0.01, 0.1, 1];
figure; hold on; linestyles = {':k', '--k', '-k'};
for nH = 1:3
    lmda = ((1/(4*pi*D))*(N/H(nH)).*u).^(2/d);    
    plot(tPulses, lmda, linestyles{nH}, 'linewidth', 2)    
end
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: That is almost spot on. Surely, I will have to check the value of `D`. But the article does say `10`. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: I can't view the article because it's behind a paywall, so I was flying blind. Hopefully playing around with the different parameters will show you how the plots change. I may be wrong, but my main thought was that it's unlikely the author would define `H` as two different things which are so different! No worries. Note: I just edited my code so it's a touch more efficient, same result